# Is Golang's Revel able to be deployed as binary?

Tags: go, revel

One of my concern about writing Web Apps using non-compiled language (Ruby, PHP, Javascript (server side), etc) is my source code can be copied and modified by another person and then they could sell it, claim it as their own. I'm seeking another language to develop my next project, and find that [Go](http://golang.org/) + [Revel](http://revel.github.io/) is quite promising in term of [speed](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=update) and feature (error line, hot code-reload)

The question is, is revel support deployment as binary?

Comment: Not trying to disuade you from trying Go, but what sort of threat are you worried about?  Employees of your hosting company covertly accessing your server and copying the application?  If the application is set up correctly, the server side source code won't be transmitted over the wire with any language.

Comment: As an outsource company, I'm worried that our work will be copied and modified without paying, with binary deployment, at least they could not (or hard) to modify where there's bugs or requirement change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang being a compiled language, everything you do with it is a binary.

What is losing you here is the hot-reload functionnality: even with it, you are still using a binary, but Revel is watching the source and compiling it again when needed.

So yes, an application written in Golang with Revel is a binary.